# How to get some PHP results in an Ionic3 application

Tags: javascript, php, json, typescript, ionic-framework

I don't know if I am right to be there, but I'm a newbie in the Ionic3 world.
I would like to create an application with Ionic, and in I'd like to get informations I have on a SQL database. On my website, I use to use AJAX method in Javascript script, and I get a response from a PHP file which got it from a SQL database with a SQL request.
The transition in Ionic and Typescript, from a website with PHP is mindblowing me.
I'm searching to do the same things in my app (with informations on my database ) that I already do on my website.
But I don't find anything specific. From where should I start ? What "technology" or programmation language should I use ?
Javascript is no longer accepted in Ionic (if I understood correctly). I found somewhere that I have to use an API, JSON files (what is JSON ?), using Typescript and some declarations... I'm not really cool with frameworks, I used to do all by myself.
Can someone help, orientate me for my searches ?
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Show us the Code that you have so far

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (used by Ionic). However, questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. You're also expected to showcase a **specific** problem.

Comment: Ok thank you, I supposed just before that I wasn't at the good place :s
But thanks for the answer, you are a good community, still being like this :)